# I want to be able to use the Unity menu with Citrix full screen

Tags: unity, appmenu, fullscreen, citrix

I use Citrix Reciever at work, with both XenApp and XenDesktop.
Many times at the same time.

Since the Unity menu still appears on the top anyway, I'd like to be able to use it. Now I can see it, but it doesn't work. I have to either tab me out, (double clicking the <kbd>Alt</kbd> first)opening another program first, or move the mouse to the left, opening another program from the Unity menu from the left, BEFORE I can use the menu on the top.
(my menu on the left side is in autohide mode, so I actually like it :))

For example.

I use Spotify for listening to music, it appears on the top menu, but it doesn't react when it click it. I have to move the mouse to the left, open another program, then move to the top an ask it to show Spotify. If I open Spotify from the left menu, it hangs. (since its hidden, and I have to ask it to be open, not reopen the hole program..)

Or, if I want to lock the screen, I have to open another program, (i.ex. NixNote) before I can lock it)
since the Unity menu is "on the top" anyways, I don't see the problem that it should be able to control such things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
edit .ICAClient/All_Regions.ini, and change:

```
TWIMode=Off
UseFullScreen=0
TWIFullScreenMode=0
```